# NoClassDefFoundError at runtime

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm receiving error "NoClassDefFoundError" at runtime after building my project using `gradle build`.

The program does start and everything seems to be working until it gets to a point where it is supposed to read some pdf files and then I receive a class not found exception. When I debug my application in intellij everything is working correctly.

When I unzip the jar file I do see that there is not a `PDFFile.class` included. Oddly enough when I build the same project on Linux I do not have this issue.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PDFFile
    at PDFViewModel$loadPdfList$1.invoke(GUI.kt:107)
    at PDFViewModel$loadPdfList$1.invoke(GUI.kt:87)
    at tornadofx.FXTask.call(Lib.kt:219)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PDFFile
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

I do have PDFFile defined.

```
data class PDFFile(val path: String, val name: String, var pages: Int?, var progress: Int?)

class PDFViewModel : ItemViewModel<PDFFile>() {
    val pdfFiles = SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<PDFFile>>()
    private val files = mutableListOf<PDFFile>()

    fun loadPdfList() {
        files.clear()
        val pdfPath = File(cfg.getProperty("pdf_path"))

        if (pdfPath.isDirectory) {
            val pdfList = pdfPath.listFiles().filter { FilenameUtils.getExtension(it.name).toLowerCase() == "pdf" }
            runAsync {
                // Set progress to 0 just in case directory is empty
                updateProgress(0.0, 1.0)
                if (pdfList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    pdfList.forEachIndexed { index, file ->
                        updateMessage("Loading ${file.name}")
                        // Load basic data about pdf files
                        PDDocument.load(file.absoluteFile).use { document ->
                            files.add(PDFFile(file.absolutePath,
                                    file.nameWithoutExtension,
                                    document.numberOfPages,
                                    0))
                            updateProgress((index + 1.0), pdfList.size.toDouble())
                        }
                    }
                }
            } ui {
                pdfFiles.set(files.observable())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my gradle.build file I have added:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'PDFStripApp'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a class in another file named `PdfFile` and in Linux since the file system is case sensitive it did not have any issue with this. In windows `PDFFile.class` and `PdfFile.class` are the same thing and thus one did not properly end up in the jar file.